# How do you call a view from one app in another

Tags: django

I have two apps the posts and home..How do I call one of the functions from my posts app in my home app. That way all information would be displayed on my home.html page.

I want a way to make a post, see a list of posts on the home.html page. I don't want to have to go to another url, I want to keep the url at /home/

home/views.py

```
from posts import views
from posts.models import Post
from posts.views import posts_list

# TODO: Found a hacky way to display all posts on home page


def home(request):
    # TODO: If the user is not authenticated then don't show the home page,
    # but instead show soe other page reporting the error. (Maybe just the login page).

    posts_list(request)
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

posts/views.py

```
def posts_list(request):
    # return HttpResponse("<h1> List a posts. </h1>")
    # TODO: Privacy stuff
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        "object_list": queryset,
        "user": "username"
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

Comment: Specify your url like `return render(request, "home/home.html", context)`

Comment: @Yuda My templates are in the root directory so its fine for me to do home.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you don't need to call the view of another app. Just use the url to redirect to the posts view.

For example, you may use:

```
from posts.views import posts_list
url('home/', posts_list, name="home"),
```

In your case you can import the view as:

```
from posts.views import posts_list
```

And in your home view:

```
posts_list(request)
```

Also:

```
return render(request, 'home.html')
```

remove this part from your home view.

If that doesnot work then you can use:

```
return redirect('posts:posts_list')
```

Then you don't need to call the posts view. Then your home view will be:

```
def home(request):
    return redirect('posts:posts_list')
```

If you don't want any change in url then you can change the home function as:

```
def home(request):
    # TODO: If the user is not authenticated then don't show the home page,
    # but instead show soe other page reporting the error. (Maybe just the login page).
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.publish = datetime.now()
            instance.save()

        queryset = Post.objects.all()
        context = {
            "object_list": queryset,
            "user": "username",
            "form":form
        }
    else:
        form = PostForm()
        queryset = Post.objects.all()
        context = {
            "object_list": queryset,
            "user": "username",
            "form":form
        }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

Then you don't need the `posts_list` and `posts_create` function in the `posts` app.